# Restricting access to package private variables when the package is used in other package

Tags: java

company xyz created a package

```
com.xyz.utils.
```

There are two classes declared in two separate files. They have some variables as package private. so that a variable X in class A can be used in class B of the same package.

```
package com.xyz.utils;
public class A{
int a=10;
}

package com.xyz.utils;
public class B{
int b = (new A()).a;
}
```

Those two files are compiled into a jar and sent to customer.

The customer add the jar to the project he is building and he writes code like below

```
package com.xyz.utils;

public  class customer_class
{
     int  Y = (new A()).a;
}
```

Is that above code is correct?

My quetsion is. how can we make variables which are declared as package private to be not visible to others when they use the package.

Comment: No, the code you've shown isn't correct, as it's basically pseudo-code. Please give a *full* code example, and it'll be easier to say whether or not it's valid. You also seem to be using the word "package" to mean two different things - my guess is that one of your uses is effectively "jar file". It would be helpful to differentiate between them.

Comment: Yeah, you should provide actual code examples for all 3 classes so that your point is very clearly illustrated.  Also, as Jon said, clarify on if you mean "jar file" or "package", it'll help get you a better answer.

Comment: THE CODE WAS CHANGED AND POSTED AGAIN.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "no" - you can't stop them from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

It can not be done in general. I think, you can [seal the package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html) 'com.xyz.utils' in in the jar manifest, to tell the user that: do not define their classes in the sealed package as a best practice. But you can not restrict the user of your library from doing it.